Getting XML error in chatgpt. It's not generating XML pages. It got stuck in a loop
For three days, chatgpt is facing some glitch of not generating XML pages at all. It got stuck in a loop. What to do now?
I tried to give a simpler XML page design that contains a textview. But chatgpt still got stuck there.

It's hard to understand what you were doing! Could you include screenshots of your chat with ChatGPT? or codes/instruction snippets you were using?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's been solved. It was a technical glitch for 4 days in chatgpt.
